# If you divide two equations by each other and you get a valid equation, does that necessarily mean original equations are also valid?

Tags: logic

Let
$$a = b$$
$$c = d$$

Assume a,b,c,d are non-zeros

If we know that $$\frac{a}{c} = \frac{b}{d}$$

Are the original equations valid? I know we can arrive at a true statement from false statements so even if original equations are not valid, the derived equation can be valid, right? I'm still confused tho because there is not really any logical mistakes in steps that could lead to a true statement from two false statements in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{4}$ but $1 \neq 2$ and $2 \neq 4$.

Comment: So there is not really any way to know if original equations are valid from derived equation? (always)

Comment: @AmirWG In general, yes. Basically if we know $p \implies q$ and $q$ is true, we still know nothing about $p$.

Comment: got it, thanks alot.